# Get incremented variable in state

Tags: reactjs

How I can get the incremented variable in the same setState?

I have the following example

https://codesandbox.io/s/jjj3k80o3y

As you can see the first is incremented correctly but the second is behind with one value.
It is possible for incrementedIndex to be the same value as currentIndex?

```
incrementAction = () => {
    this.setState({
      currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1,
      incrementedIndex: this.state.currentIndex
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React `setStates` are batched. It doesn't update the state one property at a time, in sequence.

In the second property you are still using the old version of the state, that's why it does not increment.

---

BTW, when you use the current value of the state to compute the next one, you should use the method notation, not the object one:

```
incrementAction = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    currentIndex: prevState.currentIndex + 1,
    incrementedIndex: prevState.currentIndex
  }));
};
```